# How to create custom odoo-image on docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, odoo

i am new to docker and while creating image of odoo i am very confused about the process,
i want to create an odoo image with custom-addons

i have odoo installed on my local m/c on this path /opt/odoo15

these are my dependencies( requirement.txt )

```
Babel==2.9.1  # min version = 2.6.0 (Focal with security backports)
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.6.1  # incompatibility between pyopenssl 19.0.0 and cryptography>=37.0.0
decorator==4.4.2
docutils==0.16
ebaysdk==2.1.5
freezegun==0.3.11; python_version < '3.8'
freezegun==0.3.15; python_version >= '3.8'
gevent==1.5.0 ; python_version == '3.7'
gevent==20.9.0 ; python_version > '3.7' and python_version <= '3.9'
gevent==21.8.0 ; python_version > '3.9'  # (Jammy)
greenlet==0.4.15 ; python_version == '3.7'
greenlet==0.4.17 ; python_version > '3.7' and python_version <= '3.9'
greenlet==1.1.2 ; python_version  > '3.9'  # (Jammy)
idna==2.8
Jinja2==2.11.3 # min version = 2.10.1 (Focal - with security backports)
libsass==0.18.0
lxml==4.6.5 # min version = 4.5.0 (Focal - with security backports)
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
num2words==0.5.6
ofxparse==0.19; python_version <= '3.9'
ofxparse==0.21; python_version > '3.9'  # (Jammy)
passlib==1.7.3 # min version = 1.7.2 (Focal with security backports)
Pillow==9.0.1  # min version = 7.0.0 (Focal with security backports)
polib==1.1.0
psutil==5.6.7 # min version = 5.5.1 (Focal with security backports)
psycopg2==2.7.7; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.8'
psycopg2==2.8.6; sys_platform == 'win32' or python_version >= '3.8'
pydot==1.4.1
pyopenssl==19.0.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pypiwin32 ; sys_platform == 'win32'
pyserial==3.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-ldap==3.4.0 ; sys_platform != 'win32'  # min version = 3.2.0 (Focal with security backports)
python-stdnum==1.13
pytz==2019.3
pyusb==1.0.2
qrcode==6.1
reportlab==3.5.59 # version < 3.5.54 are not compatible with Pillow 8.1.2 and 3.5.59 is bullseye
requests==2.25.1 # versions < 2.25 aren't compatible w/ urllib3 1.26. Bullseye = 2.25.1. min version = 2.22.0 (Focal)
urllib3==1.26.5 # indirect / min version = 1.25.8 (Focal with security backports)
vobject==0.9.6.1
Werkzeug==0.16.1 ; python_version <= '3.9'
Werkzeug==2.0.2 ; python_version > '3.9'  # (Jammy)
xlrd==1.1.0; python_version < '3.8'
xlrd==1.2.0; python_version >= '3.8'
XlsxWriter==1.1.2
xlwt==1.3.*
zeep==3.4.0
```

this is my Dockerfile inside odoo15 user

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /odoo-app

ADD . /odoo-app

COPY ./odoo/requirements.txt /odoo-app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /odoo-app
```

here is docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
       - POSTGRES_USER=odoo15_user
       - POSTGRES_DB=hello
     # restart: always # run as a service
     volumes:
      - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .

    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8001:8069"
     tty: true
    command: "sudo systemctl daemon reload && sudo systemctl start odoo15.service"
    # #  command: odoo scaffold /mnt/extra-addons/test_module
     environment:
       - HOST=hello
       - USER=admin
       - PASSWORD=admin
     volumes:
       #- /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
       #- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
       # - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh   # if you want to install additional Python packages, uncomment this line!
       - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
       - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    # restart: always # run as a service
```

when run docker-compose up --build getting error

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
```

any help about this will be appreciated

Comment: "*1. what should be the Dockerfile and docker-compose file ? 2 . what should be the dependencies for odoo ?*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*any feedback will be appreciated*" - We do not do review here. --- Please [edit] the post and add one specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use odoo official container in your Dockerfile to build web service instead of python3 image. This way you will not need to manually copy odoo core or install odoo dependencies.

Take a look at odoo docker [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo).

In case you need to meet custom requirements (i suppose you are installing custom modules in your container), your Dockerfile shoud look like this:

```
FROM odoo:latest

COPY ./custom-requirements.txt /opt/custom-requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /opt/custom-requirements.txt
```